Logical question involving simple probability
This is a logic question. It is not a homework.
I am bound to lose money. I want to minimize my loss. There are 2 mutually exclusive options A or B. There are 2 events that may happen, Event E1 or Event E2.
The chart in the link show more information:
Path-Probability Diagram
To explain the chart:
If I choose path A and Event E1 occurs, I lose 20k
If I choose path A and Event E2 occurs, I lose 55k
If I choose path B and either events occur, I lose 32k.
I can choose either paths A or B, but I don't know which event will happen. My objective is to loose as less as possible by choosing a path (either A or B).
What I tried is:
Since Event E2 is most likely to occur (80%), the loss in case of path A (55k) > loss of any event in path B (32k)...So maybe choosing Path B leads to less loss. Does this make sense?
Note: The entire case occurs 1 time only ever.
Thanks. 

This depends on your Utility Function. What is it exactly that you want to minimize? Your expected loss? Your worst case loss? Something else?

Note:  In this particular case, I'd imagine that every likely Utility Function would choose the same option, but in general that is not the case.

@lulu, Good question. Worst case loss would be Path B and Event 2. What would the expected loss be?

Well, you can't choose Event $2$, but that hardly matters on path $B$, since all events cost $32$.  Expected loss on Path $B$ is clearly $32$.  On Path $A$ it is $.2\times 20+.8\times 55=48$, so again Path $B$ looks more attractive.

Here's a Utility Function that would select Path $A$:  Suppose you can survive a loss of $30$ but any more than that will destroy you.  In that case, there is no meaningful difference between losing $55$ and losing $32$, as both of those destroy you.  Accordingly you take Path $A$ because at least that gives you a $20%$ chance of surviving.

@lulu, but P(E2)=80%...So we may try to choose the Min {-55k, -32k} = -32k so Path B is better in the most probable case. What do you think?

Again, you have to specify your Utility Function.  There isn't an obvious or a universal choice.  As I say, in this particular case, it looks like most utility functions are going to favor $B$ but this won't be true in general.

To make a more interesting problem, swap the probabilities along Path $A$.  In that variant, the Path $A$ expectation is only $27$...so the Utility Function that seeks to minimize expected loss now prefers $A$.  But there is still a significant chance ($20%$) of a losing $55$ along path $A$, so a Utility function that sought to minimize worst case loss, or probable worst case loss, would stick with $B$.

@lulu, thanks for your help.
